# configuring handler for SIGTSTP signal to display a message but not terminate the current process

Tags: c

I have this very basic shell program that just keeps prompting for an input until user presses control+c.

I am trying to configure the SIGTSTP signal's handler function to display a message and not terminate the program.
(SIGTSTP is triggered by control+z and by default terminates the program and all child processes.)

The problem: As soon as I press control+z, which triggers the SIGTSTP signal, the program crashes.

Below is my code which includes my basic shell program and my attempt to define the custom handler function for SIGTSTP.

Thank you for any help and suggestions!

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handle_SIGTSTP(int signo){
   char* message = "\ncontrol + z pressed\n";
   write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, 21);
   fflush(stdout);
};

int main() {
   struct sigaction SIGTSTP_custom = {0};
   SIGTSTP_custom.sa_handler = handle_SIGTSTP;
   sigaction(SIGTSTP, &SIGTSTP_custom, NULL);
   while(true) {
      char *user_input = malloc(200);
      memset(user_input, '\0', 200);
      size_t max_input_size = 199;
      printf("enter input: ");
      fflush(stdout);
      getline(&user_input, &max_input_size, stdin);
   };
   return 0;
};
```

Comment: Do note that the default action for `SIGSTP` is to *stop* the receiving process, not terminate it.  These are very different things (a stopped process can be resumed), but of course neither one is what you actually want here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the SA_RESTART flag to the sigaction structure:

```
...
   struct sigaction SIGTSTP_custom = {0};
   SIGTSTP_custom.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART; // add this
   SIGTSTP_custom.sa_handler = handle_SIGTSTP;
   sigaction(SIGTSTP, &SIGTSTP_custom, NULL);
...
```

The behavior of the signal handler will depend on those flags, information on all flags is available on the man page (man sigaction).

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the problem. The lecture never covered this flag. I guess I'll have to rely on more than lectures!

Answer (score 1):

Pablo found your main bug: you need to set the `SA_RESTART` flag to have interrupted system calls restarted.

When SIGTSTP arrives, your program is presumably waiting for I/O in `getline`, with a system call such as `read(2)`.  Without `SA_RESTART`, this system call fails when the signal arrives, and sets `errno` to `EINTR`.  The failure of `read()` causes  `getline` to set the error flag on `stdin`, which makes all successive `getline` calls fail immediately, and puts you in an infinite loop of `printf`.
If you had checked the return value from `getline()` and done proper error reporting, it would have helped you find this.

The infinite loop by itself wouldn't make your program crash, but you have another bug: you allocate memory on every iteration of the loop, and then leak it.  You really want to declare and initialize `user_input` and `max_input_size` outside your loop.  You also don't need to allocate memory yourself; you can let `getline()` do it the first time by initializing to NULL and 0.  The usual idiom for `getline` would look like:

```
char *user_input = NULL;
size_t max_input_size = 0;
while (getline(&user_input, &max_input_size, stdin) != -1) {
    // do stuff with user_input
}
// either error or EOF, handle appropriately
free(user_input);
```

And one more bug: it's not safe to call `fflush` or other stdio functions in a signal handler.  It's also not necessary because the `write()` doesn't go through the stdio buffers anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out all the other bugs, I've added the sa_flag and fixed the memory leak issue.